# Time series analysis: Determine if trend is deterministic fluctuating/stable or stochastic

Tags: r, time-series

I am analysing sales data of certain products and need to determine if the demand trend is  deterministic fluctuating or deterministic stable or stochastic.

How do I do that in R / what approach is usually applied to do so?

Quarterly values would be for example:
2424,3030,3207,2943,2631,2863,2711,2837,2839,2876,3075,2886,2520,3136,3235,3071,2923,3237,
3054,3321,2856,3389,3092,3325

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trends can be of the form

$$y(t)=a+bt+ct^2$$  OR

$$y(t)=y(t-1)+\theta_0$$ OR

$$Y(t)=a+b x_1+ c x_2$$

etc  where $x_1=1,2,3,4....t$ and $x_2=0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4$ thus one trend applies to observations $1-5$ and a second trend applies to observations $6$ to $t$.

if you wish you can post your data

EDIT after data was posted:

A plot of the ACF suggests that the series is stationary thus no trend is required. [image]. This led directly to an AR(2) model /(2,0,0)(0,0,0) with a seasonal pulse reflecting consistent first quarter effect. [image] . The residual plot shows little structure thus randomness can be reasonably accepted.[image] . This is confirmed by the ACF of the residuals [image] . The Actual/Fit/Forecast nicely summarizes the results [image]

Comment: $\TeX$ formatting is no more difficult than what you originally wrote and is *much* more readable. You can accomplish this yourself by enclosing math expressions in dollar signs (shift-4 on most keyboards).  Doubling the dollar signs will produce centered paragraph-style expressions.  BTW, how does this post answer the question?

Comment: @Whuber I should have added that the actual data is useful to empirically identify which of these states of nature is most  applicable  thus answering the question by example as there is no theoretical answer as far as I know.

Comment: I added some example data.

Comment: Re your analysis: many people, upon seeing no significant autocorrelation, would proceed to test for trend by regressing the values against time and would likely include a seasonal dummy. The result is highly significant (F(4,19)=10.06, p=0.00015); the diagnostic tests are decent; and its forecasts will be substantially greater than yours. Although that does not exactly contradict your results--these are two different procedures with different assumptions, after all--it would be interesting to consider why these two methods produce such different results.

Comment: The problem with using an ad hoc model (not based upon sound analytics )  is that if the series has a level shift you will falsely assign trend rather than a simple (permanent) movement of the mean to a new level.Notice that the seasonal dummy for the first quarter was found automatically thus proxying the human eye.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, in observational data it is difficult to distinguish the trend-stationary series from random walk. You called them deterministic and stochastic.

The trend-stationary process is $x_t=\beta_0+\beta_tt+\varepsilon_t$, while RW is $x_t=x_{t-1}+\beta_0+\varepsilon_t$.

Consider a very well researched time series such as [GDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gross_domestic_product). The economists are still debating whether it's trend-stationary or RW, e.g. see this [paper on German GDP](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/227361689_Is_Germany%27s_GDP_Trend-Stationary_A_Measurement-With_Theory_Approach/file/e0b495242c85219e5f.pdf). You can also see how they try to determine if the series is RW or not.

Comment: What would I do then, I need to justify what approach (heuristic approach for trend-stationary, stochastic for RW) I should use to determine future order quantities?

Comment: @MartinZotter, one thing is to look at what others do, e.g. that paper on German GDP. However the best approach is to come up with a good theory explaining the underlying phenomenon. For example, we have a theory for radioactive decay, and when we process its data we know which model to fit (exponential growth).